# InDesign CS6 scripting - XML-Import - Assign tags to formattings

Tags: xml, scripting, formatting, adobe-indesign

I'm implementing an automatization for Adobe InDesign CS6.

The script imports an xml-file into an exisiting InDesign-file. It imports places the xml into a textframe that is created within the scripting. This part works fine but at this point the content is not formatted. I don't know if this behaviour is correct...

The problem is I don't know how to assign the tags to the formattings with scripting. Manually you would select "Assing tags to formattings" via the drop down menu in the Structure-explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Map tags to styles?

then give this a try...

```
app.activeDocument.mapXMLTagsToStyles();
```